# Did the angel preach the Gospel to Mary Magdalene and the other Mary?

Tags: angels

Matthew 28:6 New International Version

> He is not here; he has risen, **just as he said**. Come and see the place where he lay.

The angel stated that the resurrection of Jesus happened exactly as he had predicted during his earthly ministry. Jesus anticipated his own resurrection multiple times throughout his teachings, and this statement underscores the faithfulness and truthfulness of his words. Therefore, the angel declared that the resurrection event aligns with the words spoken by Jesus earlier.

**Did the angel preach the Gospel to Mary Magdalene and the other Mary?**

Answer (score 1):

There are several records that Jesus said He was going to die and He even gave some details about how His death would happen.

- Matt 16:21 - and that he must be killed and on the third day be raised to life.
- Matt 17:23 - They will kill him, and on the third day he will be raised to life.
- Matt 20:19 - and will hand him over to the Gentiles to be mocked and flogged and crucified. On the third day He will be raised to life!
- Mark 9:31 - They will kill him, but on the third day He will come back to life.
- Mark 10:34 - who will mock him and spit on him, flog him and kill him. Three days later He will rise.
- Luke 18:33 - they will flog him and kill him. On the third day He will rise again.
- Luke 9:22 - The Son of Man must suffer many things and be rejected by the elders, the chief priests and the teachers of the law, and He must be killed and on the third day be raised to life.

Thus, the disciples, including the women who were with them, were told a number of times that Jesus would be cruelly killed and rise again.

There is no record of the angel saying anything other than what the gospels record.  This does not include any preaching of the gospel.  The record of what the angel said to the women is given below:

- Matt 28:5-7 - But the angel said to the women, “Do not be afraid, for I know that you are looking for Jesus, who was crucified. He is not here; He has risen, just as He said! Come, see the place where He lay. Then go quickly and tell His disciples, ‘He has risen from the dead and is going ahead of you into Galilee. There you will see Him.’ See, I have told you.”
- Mark 16:6, 7 - But he said to them, “Do not be alarmed. You are looking for Jesus the Nazarene, who was crucified. He has risen! He is not here! See the place where they put Him. But go, tell His disciples and Peter, ‘He is going ahead of you into Galilee. There you will see Him, just as He told you.’ ”
- Luke 24:5-7 - As the women bowed their faces to the ground in terror, the two men asked them, “Why do you look for the living among the dead? He is not here; He has risen! Remember how He told you while He was still in Galilee: ‘The Son of Man must be delivered into the hands of sinful men, and be crucified, and on the third day rise again.’”  Then they remembered His words.

Answer (score 0):

> And Jesus returned (from being tempted by the devil) in the power of
> the Spirit into Galilee: and there went out a fame of him through all
> the region round about.
>
> And he taught in their synagogues, being glorified of all. Luke
> 4:14-15

In Matthew we see the same timeline, Jesus being tempted
and then fame and then teaching: Matthew 4:1-24.
In Matthew we have a detailed account of what Jesus taught; Matthew 5 through 7.

Putting the accounts together we can understand
what Jesus meant by 'gospel' in Luke 4;
he was talking about his teachings.

> The Spirit of the Lord is upon me because **he has appointed me to
> preach the gospel** to the poor.... This days is this scripture
> fulfilled in your ears Luke 4:18-21

After Jesus died and rose from the dead he tells his disciples to go into the world
and teach people his teachings.

> Go ye therefore and teach all nations. Baptizing them... teaching them to observe
> whatsoever I have commanded you. Matthew 28:19-20

The good news, the gospel, is what Jesus taught, his words, his teachings,
not just that he died and rose from the dead.

> Believe on the Lord Jesus Christ and you shall be saved, **and your
> house**.
> **And they told him all the word of the Lord and to all that were in his house.**
> ... **and was baptized, he and all his, straightaway.** Acts 16:31-33

Notice that the apostles did just as Jesus had instructed in Matthew 28:19-20
they told them his teachings and they baptized them.

It is words such as 'give and it will be given to you...'
that are to be believed, Jesus himself is to be believed.

And therefore for the angel to have preached the gospel he would have needed to declare something about Jesus' teachings/way of life.